# ActiveRecord, polymorphic has_many, :through, :as

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails and I'm having a superb deal of difficulty wrapping my head around what seems to be a very simple database structure, but I'm thrown by the idea that objects must belong to other objects.

In a site that I am creating, a *User* may create many *Posts*.

A *Post* may fit into any number of many different Topics.

So what Rails would like is that *Posts* belong to both *Topics* and to *Users*, while *Topics* also belong to *Posts* (many-to-many?). This makes some sense in my head, but then I can't imagine how to create a *Topic* independent of a *Post* (which is reasonable to the site's function).

Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated - this is giving me a headache!

Comment: Many-to-many associations imply linkage through an extra table. `has_many <...> through: <...>` makes use of a separate model and `has_and_belongs_to_many` uses a special table without a model. Have you read [through this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)? Also, `polymorphic` is useless here, don't rush at this stuff just yet :)

Comment: HABTM is gone in rails 4.1 https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14682. They've just kept the terminology, but everything is `has_many` `through` under the hood.

Comment: Post should have `user_id` and a `join table` between it and `topics`. Just make a form for creating new topics completely independent of posts and ignore who created what topic, just let anyone. This is a practice app on localhost so you don't have to actually worry about security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`has_and_belongs_to_many` (HABTM)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) for this kind of relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

in addition to the tables for users, posts and topics, you will need to create a migration for the HABTM relationship:

```
rails g migration create_posts_users post:references user:references
```

Note that the model names appear in alphabetical order in the table name

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using polymorhpic relations here, just a *regular* many-to-many relation. Your model relations should look something like:

```
class User
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  has_many :post_topics
  has_many :topics, through: :post_topics
  belongs_to :user
end

class Topic
  has_many :post_topics
  has_many :posts, through: :post_topics
end

class PostTopic
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is perfectly fine, a **Topic** can have may **Posts**, and a **Post** can have many **Topics**, which is a many-to-many relationship. In rails that would generally translate to **`has_and_belongs_to_many`**. Therefore you can define your models as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics 
end  
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts 
end
```

The corresponding generated Migration and database tables will look like this:

```
class CreatePotsAndTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration 
def change   
  create_table :posts do |t|     
  t.string :title     
  t.timestamps   
end  

create_table :topics do |t|     
  t.string :name     
  t.timestamps   
end   

create_table :posts_topics, id: false do |t|     
  t.belongs_to :post     
  t.belongs_to :topic   
end

end 
end
```

As you can see both Topic and Post tables are standalone tables with no reference to any other table, which means they can be treated on their own. they way they get linked is through the `posts_topics` join table. Which enables you to do have access to `@post.topics` and `@topic.posts`

If you are uncomfortable with such a scenarios pick up a good rails book or do an online tutorial or course which walk you through creating a full rails application.